# Package Configurations not working SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I enabled package configurations using SSIS 2012, but when I execute my package through the debugger, the values are not being read from the package. I can tell by stepping through the script tasks and also I can see the values for variables do not change as they did when the config files were read in SSIS 2008.  Is there something more that I need to do other than enable package configurations and point to the files?
Thanks

Comment: I think the problem occured during the migration from 2008 to 2012. I migrated the packages again and unchecked 'ignore config files' which was checked by default. I'm thinking this may have been the problem, but still not completely sure.

Comment: Is it working now, or no?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Not sure how to mark the question as solved.

Comment: If you are sure of what solved the problem, you can post it as an answer yourself and mark it as the answer.   That will close the question.   If you are not sure of the answer, you can just delete the question, since it will be unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During migration from SSIS 2008 to SSIS 2012 there is an option checked by default that says 'ignore config files.' If you're using config files make sure to uncheck this box. This solved my problem.